# Проблема с basic auth, nginx и kibana

Tags: linux, nginx, auth, docker

Есть nginx сервер и kibana, оба находятся в докере. Я пытаюсь настроить прокси с basic auth и проблема в том, что при загрузке js скриптов kibana просит залогиниться по 2 разу.

Версия kibana 4.4

### Конфиг nginx:

```
server {
listen 80;

location / {
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.22:5601;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;        
}
```

### Пример ошибки:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
commons.bundle.js?v=9689:59344 Error: unhandled courier request error: Authentication Exception
    at handleError (http://ip:8090/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9689:78865:23)
    at DocRequest.AbstractReqProvider.AbstractReq.handleFailure (http://ip:8090/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9689:78785:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел сам решение, проблема была в том, что заголовок авторизации от proxy передавался в kibana и создавал конфликт.

### Исправленный конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.22:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Authorization "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;        
    }
}
```